# How do I use the Solana wallet adapter to create my own wallet connection button?

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter

I'm building a React dapp and I want to allow my users to connect their Phantom wallets to it. The [wallet adapter maintained by Solana](https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter) does everything I need, but all the examples and docs assume that I want to use their UI component for the connect button. I want a button that I can style how I want that immediately attempts to connect to Phantom instead of prompting the user with what wallet type they want. I see a `connect` function in the `useWallet` hook but can't figure out how to use it (the `disconnect` function works fine) — how can I create my own component for this?

Comment: consider adding some example code and more explicitly describing what you've attempted to get `connect` to work and how it has failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow the simple approach mentioned below for Phantom wallet, if you don't want to use the wallet adapter package.

```
 // to do transactions using the selected wallet you can expose a onWalletConnect prop, that return the selectedWallet

  function PhantomWallet (onWalletConnect) { 
    const [selectedWallet, setSelectedWallet] = useState(undefined); 
    const [isConnected, setConnected] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
      if (selectedWallet) {
        selectedWallet.connect();

        selectedWallet.on('connect', () => {
            setConnected(true);
            console.log('Connected to wallet ' + selectedWallet.publicKey.toBase58());
            console.log('selected wallet', selectedWallet);
            onWalletConnect(selectedWallet);
        });

        selectedWallet.on('disconnect', () => {
            setConnected(false);
            console.log('Disconnected from wallet');
        });
        return () => {
            selectedWallet.disconnect();
        };
     }
    }, [selectedWallet]);

   const handleButtonClick = () => { 
     if (window.solana) { // when the Phantom extension is installed, solana is set on window
         setSelectedWallet(window.solana);
     } else {
         console.log('Phantom not available, get it from here, https://phantom.app/');
     }
   }

  // you can render the connect button conditionally based on isConnected state
  return (
    <button onClick={handleButtonClick}>
      <img src={phantomIcon}></img>
      <span>Connect using Phantom</span>
    </button>);
```

Answer (score 3):

The wallet adapter is split into the [core](https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/tree/master/packages/core/react) and [UI](https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/tree/master/packages/ui/react-ui) packages.

If you want to create your own UI you can create a wrapper over the core package similarly to how the UI package works.

You can fork the [UI](https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/tree/master/packages/ui/react-ui) package and tweak it to your desired style and functionality.